# jQuery detect ajax finish inside change function

Tags: jquery

Hope my title is not misleading. I have some ajax inside change event. For example:

```
$("#my-object").change(function(){
    $.get( ... );
});
```

Is it possible to detect ajax finish with calling change():

```
$("#my-object").change().functionToCallAfterAjaxInChangeCompleted();
```

So far my only idea was to write some funcitonalities in `.change(function()..)` itself, but it's not the way I want it.

Comment: $.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "filename.php",
   data: dataString,
   success: function(msg){       functionToCallAfterAjaxInChangeCompleted()      
   }
   }); //END $.ajax

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you use [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/) instead of `.change()` to fire the event you can pass an additional parameter to the event handler

```
$("#my-object").change(function(eventObj, additionalParam) {
    $.get(...).done(additionalParam.done);
}).trigger("change", { 
    done: function() {
        alert("ajax finished"); 
    }
});
```

[Example](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/)

Comment: When the `change` event is triggered, we pass a plain object as an additional parameter into the event handler. In this object you can add what ever you want - in this case the `done` handler for your `.get()` request. In the `change` handler we finally register it as the with `.done(...)` and that's all. No black magic :)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using the promise interface:

```
// Assign handlers immediately after making the request,
// and remember the jqxhr object for this request
var jqxhr = $.get(...);

jqxhr.done(function () {
    functionToCallAfterAjaxInChangeCompleted()
});
```

Comment: THat's quite close what I want, but i'd like to `change` method to return jqxhr object, is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

As said in the [JQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get/), you can call your function in the **success** callback:

```
$("#my-object").change(function(){
  $.get( "someurl.com", function( data ) {
    ... // process your ajax data
    functionToCallAfterAjaxInChangeCompleted()
  });
});
```